# using ng-repeat with bootstrap's progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create this progress bar (https://plnkr.co/edit/LKt0PmMjPjBzY34JTsRR?p=preview) using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="progress" style="transform: rotate(-90deg); width: 494px">
 <div ng-repeat="o in arr">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:5px;"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:1px; background:transparent;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

However, it's not working because Bootstrap doesn't accept that extra `div` I'm using for the `ng-repeat`. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here's a live Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q9QW2Pn08uYrHllHb9oa?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just repeat `green` element itself:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="progress" style="transform: rotate(-90deg); width: 494px">
      <green ng-repeat="o in arr"></green>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/f1Tqfu5O9GsJiy4Nt7tk?p=preview